# How to configure springboot to allow make requests from ip 10.0.2.2

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I want to test my angular app on virtual MacOS but the problem is that I use 10.0.2.2 ip to connect to the ressources. What should I do in in my springboot app to be able to access and from localhost and from 10.0.2.2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

### 1) Let the Angular dev server proxy your backend requests to your backend

You need to create a file `proxy.conf.json` and reference it in your `angular.json` file:

```json
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            ...
       --> "proxyConfig": "proxy.conf.json" <-- 
          },
          ...
        }
```

In your `proxy.conf.json` you define which paths you want to proxy to which host. Let's say your API requests are all prefixed with `/api` and your Spring backend is running on port `1234` you'd need the following config:

```json
{
  "/api/*": {
    "target": "http://localhost:1234",
    "secure": false
  }
}
```

You then need to make sure, that your requests in the development mode are only relative and do not include the hostname. You can achieve that by having a key called `BACKEND_URL` in your `environment.ts` which is an empty string in development and the actual URL in the `environment.prod.ts`. You then need to use that key in your services that make calls to your backend.

More information can be found in the [official Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server).

### 2) Set the `@CrossOrigin` annotation on your controllers / controller endpoints

You can directly specify which hosts should be allowed to access your endpoints. As you need to achieve this only for testing / development purposes, I suggest that you stick to the first method so that you don't have development related code in your production code.

Example from [a Spring guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/) adapted to your IP address:

```java
@RestController
public class GreetingController {

    private static final String template = "Hello, %s!";

    private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

    @CrossOrigin(origins = "10.0.2.2")
    @GetMapping("/greeting")
    public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "World") String name) {
        System.out.println("==== get greeting ====");
        return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(), String.format(template, name));
    }

}
```

Here a [Baeldung article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cors) on this topic and of course the [official Spring reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/integrations/cors.html).